# How good is a Git submodule here?

Tags: git, integration, jruby, artifactory

We have a jRuby frontend (maintained using Git) integrated with a Scala backend (maintained using Artifactory). The backend JAR files are located in `/lib/jars`.

As of now, whenever a JAR file is updated, we download that JAR file and copy it to `/lib/jars`. We don't add the JAR file to Git (space, speed, etc.) and so we cannot track which JAR file went with a particular frontend commit.

We want to achieve it as follows,

1. Frontend at v1.1, backend at v1
2. Frontend at v1.1, backend goes to v2
3. Frontend now at v1.2 (force user to update the JAR file), backend at v2
4. Frontend goes to v2.2, backend at v2
5. Frontend at v2.2, backend goes to v3
6. Frontend now at v2.3 (force the user to update the JAR file), backend at v3

Whenever the backend is updated, is there a way to tell the frontend developer that the backend has been updated, and need to do something like "git pull" to get the latest JAR file that was pushed by the backend developer into Artifactory?

Possible Solution

==========================

1. Backend developer builds developer and pushes to Artifactory
2. That build process also updates the version number of the JAR file in config/jars.rb in the frontend application.
3. Frontend Git pull downloads the latest JAR file (but it does not add this JAR file to the commit) if there is a change in `config/jars.rb`.

==========================

** Ultimately, the issue is with tracking which version of the JAR file went in a particular frontend commit without storing that JAR file in the frontend repository (since it already exists in Artifactory)**

Does a Git submodule work in this case? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused.  You can't look at config/jars.rb to see which version goes with that commit?

Comment: I suggested that (the 3 steps) as a possible solution. Sorry for not being clearer

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question,  Artifactory's Build Integration feature should do the job. It will allow you to trace each built jar back to the git commit which triggered the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple Artifactory [plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) that intercepts the afterCreate() event to update the frontend config with references to newly deployed backend jars. Plugins are part of Artifactory Pro.